# I get an error in the button click listener (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android-studio, button, nullpointerexception, nullreferenceexception

I made an app to send mail separately and I am trying to implement it within another app, well it gives me this error Attempt to invoke virtual method

'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener (android.view.View $ OnClickListener)' on a null object reference

I have the id well that I know and the way to put the button and the click listener are well located. What can the error give?

this is my code

```
public class ContactFragment extends Fragment  {

//public EditText mEmail;
public EditText mSubject;
public EditText mMessage;
private Button buttonSend_contact;


private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";


private String mParam1;
private String mParam2;

public ContactFragment() {

}



public static ContactFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
ContactFragment fragment = new ContactFragment();
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
fragment.setArguments(args);
return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
if (getArguments() != null) {
    mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
    mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
}
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_videos, container, false);

mMessage = view.findViewById(R.id.messageID);
mSubject = view.findViewById(R.id.subjectID);

buttonSend_contact =  view.findViewById(R.id.buttonSendMail);

buttonSend_contact.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        sendMail();
    }
});




return view;
}
private void sendMail() {

String mail = "turespawnofficial@gmail.com";
String message = mMessage.getText().toString();
String subject = mSubject.getText().toString().trim();

//Send Mail
JavaMailAPI javaMailAPI = new JavaMailAPI(getActivity(),mail,subject,message);

javaMailAPI.execute();

}
```

this is my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".ContactFragment">

<!-- <EditText
android:id="@+id/mailID"
android:layout_margin="10dp"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:hint="Email"/> -->

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/subjectID"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:hint="Subject" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/messageID"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:hint="Message" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonSendMail"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button" />
</LinearLayout>


</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Looks like you're inflating the wrong layout there: `inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_videos, container, false)`. Should that be `R.layout.fragment_contact` instead?

Comment: omg its true, i'm so thankful, pls put your comment like an answer to give u a green tick and +1

Comment: No problem. I'm good, however. :-) Nothing major; basically just a typo. Thanks, though. I appreciate the offer. Glad it helped. Cheers!